# ServiceStack OrmLite raising MissingMethodException when selecting objects with references

Tags: c#, sql-server, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm attempting what I thought was going to be a simple select across two database tables. I'm selecting from an association table called `PlayerEquipment` that looks like this:

```
 PlayerId | ItemId | Quantity | IsEquipped
----------+--------+----------+------------
 1          1        1          1
 1          3        1          0
```

This makes up a player's inventory in our system, mapping to specific IDs in our `Player` and `Item` tables.

The associated `PlayerEquipment` POCO looks like this:

```
public class PlayerEquipment
{
    [Ignore]
    public string Id
    {
        get { return PlayerId + "/" + ItemId; }
    }

    public int PlayerId { get; set; }

    [References(typeof(ItemData))]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public bool IsEquipped { get; set; }

    [Reference]
    public ItemData ItemData { get; set; }
}
```

For now, ignore the fact that `PlayerId` isn't associated with a relevant `Player` object (it will be, eventually).

I'm trying to get a list of equipment for a player, given his ID:

```
List<PlayerEquipment> equipment = this.Db.LoadSelect<PlayerEquipment>(q => q.PlayerId == playerId);
```

When I do that call, I get this exception:

```
Method not found: 'Boolean ServiceStack.EnumerableExtensions.IsEmpty(System.__Canon[])'.
```

...with this stack trace:

```
at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteReadCommandExtensions.LoadListWithReferences[Into,From](IDbCommand dbCmd, SqlExpression`1 expr, String[] include)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.ReadExpressionCommandExtensions.LoadSelect[T](IDbCommand dbCmd, Expression`1 predicate, String[] include)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteReadExpressionsApi.<>c__DisplayClass34`1.<LoadSelect>b__33(IDbCommand dbCmd)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteExecFilter.Exec[T](IDbConnection dbConn, Func`2 filter)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteReadExpressionsApi.Exec[T](IDbConnection dbConn, Func`2 filter)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteReadExpressionsApi.LoadSelect[T](IDbConnection dbConn, Expression`1 predicate, String[] include)
   [snip]
```

Looking online, I haven't found any help for this exception, but I can't imagine how I could make my query any simpler. Am I going about this in the wrong way? Should I instead query a `Player` or `Item` object that references a `List<PlayerEquipment>` property instead?

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried this example in all supported Databases and it's working as expected. The only change was removing `[Ignore]` which is not allowed on Primary Keys as they need to exist on the underlying RDBMS table.

#### Types Used

```
public class PlayerEquipment
{
    public string Id
    {
        get { return PlayerId + "/" + ItemId; }
    }

    public int PlayerId { get; set; }

    [References(typeof(ItemData))]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public bool IsEquipped { get; set; }

    [Reference]
    public ItemData ItemData { get; set; }
}

public class ItemData
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

#### Create Tables, Populate Data, Select and Dump Results

```
db.DropTable<PlayerEquipment>();
db.DropTable<ItemData>();

db.CreateTable<ItemData>();
db.CreateTable<PlayerEquipment>();

var item1 = new ItemData { Data = "ITEM1" };
db.Save(item1);

db.Save(new PlayerEquipment
{
    PlayerId = 1,
    ItemId = item1.Id,
    Quantity = 1,
    IsEquipped = true,
});

var item2 = new ItemData { Data = "ITEM2" };
db.Save(item2);

db.Save(new PlayerEquipment
{
    PlayerId = 1,
    ItemId = item2.Id,
    Quantity = 1,
    IsEquipped = false,
});

var playerId = 1;
var results = db.LoadSelect<PlayerEquipment>(q => q.PlayerId == playerId);

results.PrintDump();
```

#### Console Output

```
[
    {
        Id: 1/1,
        PlayerId: 1,
        ItemId: 1,
        Quantity: 1,
        IsEquipped: True,
        ItemData: 
        {
            Id: 1,
            Data: ITEM1
        }
    },
    {
        Id: 1/2,
        PlayerId: 1,
        ItemId: 2,
        Quantity: 1,
        IsEquipped: False,
        ItemData: 
        {
            Id: 2,
            Data: ITEM2
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: I'm still seeing this issue, but I realize that I accidentally left out some information, originally:

- The backing table for `ItemData` is called `Item` (I have an `[Alias("item")]` declaration on the `Item` class). I'd like it to be consistent, but we have an existing `Item` class used for something else.
- I don't actually have an `id` column on the `PlayerEquipment` table. The primary key is a composite of `PlayerId` and `ItemId`. Do I need an actual `id` column as well, even though I'll always use one of those two columns to query for data?

Comment: @Monkey34 yes it needs a column for the primary key. Can you put together a stand-alone gist that I can run that repro's the issue?